# TextBlock not showing up in ListView

Tags: c#, wpf, listview, mvvm

This is my ListView:

```
<ListView ItemsSource="{Binding ModuleList}">
    <ListView.ItemTemplate>
        <DataTemplate>
            <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal">
                <!--<Image Source="{Binding ModuleImage}" Stretch="UniformToFill"/>-->
                <TextBlock Text="{Binding ModuleName}"/>
            </StackPanel>
        </DataTemplate>
    </ListView.ItemTemplate>
</ListView>
```

This is the code in WPF (MVVM):

```
public ItemListViewVM() : base()
{
    ModuleList = new List<Module>();

    modulLoader.LoadAllModules();
    tempModulList = modulLoader.GetAllModules();

    foreach (var module in tempModulList)
    {
        ModuleImage = module.ModuleImage;
        ModuleName = module.Name;
        ModuleList.Add(module);
    }
}
```

Long story short: The List `tempModulList` contains Objects of type `Module`, which has an ImageSource `Image` and a string `Name`. Then the ModuleList gets one item after another. When I uncomment the Image in xaml, you can see it. But the TextBlock won't show up no matter what. I checked the string `module.Name`for every item, it is not empty.

**EDIT: Add Module Class**
The Module Class just contains Name and Image:

```
public class Module
{
    public ImageSource ModuleImage { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
}
```

The Object gets created by deserializing a Json

Comment: Is the DataContext of the Control set correctly?

Comment: It's this: `<Grid.DataContext>
            <vm:ItemListViewVM/>
        </Grid.DataContext>`

Comment: You should of course also show the declaration of the Module class. Besides that, the foreach loop in the ItemListViewVM constructor seems pointless. What's the purpose of the ModuleImage and ModuleName properties or fields there? Why don't you just have `ModuleList =  modulLoader.GetAllModules();`?

Comment: Cause I want `ModuleImage` and `ModuleName` to show in the List. If i just do `ModuleList = modulLoader.GetAllModules();` It shows nothing, cause both  `ModuleImage` and `ModuleName` are not set

Comment: Change the background color of TextBlock to see if the control is visible.

Comment: I didn't know how to set Image and Name of every item to show in the list, so I made it with properties

Comment: That makes no sense at all. If you add `Module` instances to the `ModuleList` collection, these instances are supposed to be displayed in the ListView. Any other properties or variables are irrelevant.

Comment: I've added `Background="White" Foreground="Black"` but it changes nothing

Comment: @Clemens As you can see in the Xaml, I want an Image and a text to be shown. They are bound to ModulImage and ModulName. When ModuleImage contains an Image, this image gets shown. If ModuleName contains a string, this string won't show up

Comment: Sure, that are the two properties in a `Module`. What are the properties or variables inside the loop? I.e. `ModuleImage = module.ModuleImage;` and `ModuleName = module.Name;`?

Comment: You're right, that did it. I thought, as the DataContext is ItemListViewVM, I need to have properties there to show them in the List, and not just the Properties of the Item itself

Comment: I changed `ModuleName` in the Xaml to `Name` and it worked. I thought I need to use the Properties of `ItemListViewVM` and not `Module`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The Bindings in the ItemTemplate use the properties of the data item class as their source properties. Hence you should write

```
Text="{Binding Name}"
```

instead of

```
Text="{Binding ModuleName}"
```

Unless you set the `View` property of a ListView (to e.g. a `GridView`)  you could also better use a ListBox, which is the base class of ListView, and simpler:

```
<ListBox ItemsSource="{Binding ModuleList}">
    <ListBox.ItemTemplate>
        <DataTemplate>
            <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal">
                <Image Source="{Binding ModuleImage}"/>
                <TextBlock Text="{Binding Name}"/>
            </StackPanel>
        </DataTemplate>
    </ListBox.ItemTemplate>
</ListBox>
```

Initializing the `ModuleList` property in the view model constructor would be as simple as this:

```
public ItemListViewVM()
{
    modulLoader.LoadAllModules();
    ModuleList = modulLoader.GetAllModules();
}
```